# Height, flex-grow, and min-height not behaving correctly in flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was having issues with a div that has a dynamic height that is scrollable inside a flex-box. The sample below shows what is happening.

- Why don't the pixel units of `height` translate `1:1` inside a flexed box?
- Why DO the pixel units of `min-height` translate `1:1` inside a flexed box?

You can see for yourself by adding more content to both `.content.mid` elements, the box with `min-height` retains it's height of `30px` yet the box with `height` gets smaller and smaller as the `flex-grow` container gets bigger and bigger.

This was tested on Chrome/53.0.2785.143

```css
.content{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction:column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left:10px;
  top: 10px;
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
}

.content div{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.mid{
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow:auto;
}
.top,.bot{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height:30px;
}
.content.bad{
  left:320px;
}
.top.bad,.bot.bad{
  min-height:auto; /* reset min-height */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="top">actual height = 30px (with min-height)</div>
  <div class="mid">scrollable<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br></div>
  <div class="bot">actual height = 30px (with min-height)</div>
</div>

<div class="bad content">
  <div class="bad top">actual height != 30px (with height)</div>
  <div class="bad mid">scrollable<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br></div>
  <div class="bad bot">actual height != 30px (with height)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-shrink: 1`. This means that, by default, flex items will be allowed to shrink past their initial size. Disable this feature with `flex-shrink: 0` on items that should retain their defined `width` / `height` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jugcqmny/)). For a more complete explanation, see ***The `flex-shrink` factor*** section in the dupe.